# Why this random variable $Y$ is continuous?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I given the DPF : $$F_Y(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} \frac{1}{4 \log |t| } & t < -e \\ \frac14 & -e \leq t < 3 \\ 1 - \frac{27}{4 t^2} & t \geq 3 \end{array}\right.$$ why is necessary mean that $Y$ is continuous?

If I understood it right, the idea here is to find a density function $f_y$ such that the integral $\int f_y =F_Y(t)$
but I cant find the function for the section $[-e,3)$.

what is the way I need to think on this problem?

Comment: "Continuous" simply means that the support of the distribution is the real numbers (or some intervals thereof).

Comment: Two ways to approach this.  1.  $f_Y(t) = \frac{d}{dt} F_Y(t)$ (where the latter is differentiable); what does this yield?  2.  The probability that $Y < -e$ is $F_Y(-e) = 1/4$.  The probability that $Y < 3$ is $F_Y(3) = 1/4$.  What does this imply?

Comment: @BrianTung according to your first tip, I am getting that $f_y=0$ in the interval $[-e,3)$ since the derivative of constant is zero. is that what you meant to?
according to the second tip, I did not understand your meaning

Comment: The CDF of a continuous random variable is continuous _everywhere_ and is differentiable everywhere except possibly for a finite set of points. What Brian Tung is pointing out to you is that the CDF you have is continuous everywhere. Perhaps it is not differentiable at $e$ and $3$?